# Is Flow API replacing Observer and Observable

Tags: reactive-programming, observer-pattern, java-9

In Java 9 does [Flow API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html) replace [Observer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) and [Observable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)? If not, what does?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The new Flow API](https://blog.codefx.org/java/reactive-http-2-requests-responses/#Reactive-Stream-Crash-Course) is designed as a common denominator for [reactive stream](http://www.reactive-streams.org/) libraries like RxJava and Reactive X. Building on Java 9, they can have their types extend the new interfaces (or so the thought goes). While it is of course charming to use the API inside the JDK, that is not the case in Java 9 and there are no concrete plans to introduce it (to the best of my knowledge).

Regarding `Observer` and `Observable` [the issue which triggered the deprecation](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154801) states:

> Application developers should consider using java.beans for a richer change notification model. Or they should consider constructs in java.util.concurrent such as queues or semaphores to pass messages among threads, with reliable ordering and synchronization properties.

These are recommendations for application developers for writing new code. It gives no advice on updating existing code or what to do inside the JDK. I guess the reason for that is that both cases are supposed to stay as they are.

Note that Java does not use `@Deprecated` to necessarily mean "will be removed". Instead it can also mean "use better alternatives" and I think that is the case here. So to answer your question in a few words:

> In Java 9 does Flow API replace Observer and Observable

No.

> and if it doesn't what does.

Nothing.

Comment: +1. Note that since [JEP 277](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/277) an API could also be earmarked for removal in a future release using the `@Deprecated` annotation. I'm not aware that this new possibility has been used up to now. It could in the future, but I doubt that they would ever deprecate Observer/Observable "forRemoval".

Comment: Java 9 actually removes some methods that were deprecated in Java 8. I have no idea whether that is the first time but it is surely not common. I never meant to say that `@Deprecated` _never_ means that something might be removed but my phrasing was ambiguous. Thanks to your comment I realized that and put in a _necessarily_.

Comment: That's interesting. Can you share an example?

Comment: Sure. :) Six methods adding/removing `PropertyChangeListener` got removed from [`LogManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html), [`Pack200.Packer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/Pack200.Packer.html), and [`Pack200.Unpacker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/Pack200.Unpacker.html) (search for _Deprecated_). They were removed because they would have created cycles between modules.

Comment: And I think this is indeed the first time anything has actually been removed, so this is pretty news worthy.